# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: MarkupExtension not found

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, markup-extensions

I am attempting to use a a custom markup extension with Xamarin forms in order to eventually having localization implemented. I am trying to go a long the lines of the Xamarin form examples.

Here is a pieces of XAML Code that uses the extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CRI.MAP.Mobile.Views;assembly=CRI.MAP.Mobile"
    x:Class="CRI.MAP.Mobile.Views.CustomerSearchPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Button 
            Text="{local:Translate Clear}"  
            Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is the code for the Translation Extension Markup:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CRI.MAP.Mobile.Views
{
    // You exclude the 'Extension' suffix when using in Xaml markup
    [ContentProperty ("Text")]
    public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            //if (Text == null)
            //  return null;
            //Debug.WriteLine ("Provide: " + Text);
            // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
            //var translated = L10n.Localize (Text); 

            //return translated;
            return "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

I commented out some of the code just in case that was the cause of the issue.

Whenever I attempt to run this I get the error: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: MarkupExtension not found for local:Translate. I am very confused as why it doesn't find the the markup extension as all the examples I look at seem to be done the same way. Does anybody know why this would be? I am having a lot of troubles in general finding good examples for Xamarin forms.

Answer (score 4):

The assembly name is wrong. I was using a shared project for Xamarin forms and had the name of the shared project as the name of the assembly.  So if you have a shared project the name of the assembly needs to be the assembly that is using the shared project.

Comment: Hi Michelle, thanks for sharing! How did you manage to handle the different namespaces (iOS, Droid, WinPhone) from XAML? I Mean if your assembly is ```assembly=MyApp``` you will need to change to ```assembly=MyApp.WinPhone``` when building for WP, ```MyApp.Droid``` when building for Android, usw...

Comment: Remember I am doing a shared project so I made it be the same assembly name for each project. The assembly name is defined in the  build properties in each of the projects for iOS, Android, and Windows. The namespace referred to the name space I wrote the extension in. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, I ended up with the same solution. Xamarin rocks ;)

Comment: I had a similar error message when I spelt 'binding' with a lowercase b instead of a capital, e.g (wrong)., <Label Text="{binding Date, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" />

Comment: Damien Sawyer, you saved my day, it was 'Bindig' in my case. It should be another answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

In My case It was not working when I was connecting to iPhone and it was start working after make changes as below

### Open Ios Project

---

1. Open Options/ property window
2. Go to tab iOS Build
3. Linker Behavior : Link Framework SDK Only (If already selected it then change with Link All )